# how to use a specific namespace, or global namespace in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using a library that is "smartly" exporting a namespace `Math` from their library

`import { Tool, Math } from 'library';`

The problem is, when I use the library's Math, I am also using some native Math function from the browser.

Is there a way to specify which namespace to use ?

```
Math.customLib()
Math.nativeMath()
```

how to tell ts which one to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `as` syntax to create the import item name.

```
import { Tool, Math as MathFromLibrary } from 'library';
```